# Looking for a terminology in ring theory ("ideal" which is not necessarily closed under addition )

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, terminology, ideals

I am wondering if there is a name for the subsets $S$ of a commutative ring $R$ such that for every $r\in R$ and every $s\in S$ we have $rs\in S$.

Thus $S$ is `almost` an ideal except that it is not closed under addition.

**Example**: unions of some ideals in a commutative ring.

Comment: Interesting question. I personally haven't seen such a word used (probably because I've never seen this idea discussed.)

Comment: Candidate if there is no term: idel? Ideal without addition?

Comment: @rschwieb interesting suggestion. But before it, I am interested to know if there exists a terminology already used in the literature.

Comment: @rschwieb The word [idele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelic_algebraic_group#Ideles) is already used (even though the spelling is different)...

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon I remembered "adele" but I must have forgotten "idele" :) Yes, "idel" would be altogether too close to those. The temptation to mimic "rng" and "rig" was too great for me :)

Comment: I support the Adele idea.

Answer (score 2):

In the semigroup theory S is called a left ideal in the semigroup R under multiplication. See any semigroup theory book (J.M.Howie: Semigroup theory for example)

Comment: This can hardly help imo, as a semigroup has only one operation defined on it and not two, as rings require.

Comment: @Timbuc Then again, the definition itself ignores addition, so what more could you expect?

Comment: Oh, I expect nothing. I only think this answer might not be what the OP is looking for as it does **not**  use the fact we're in a *ring*', an algebraic structure with two binary operations defined on it. That's all.

Comment: @MattSamuel In fact I am interested in a terminology used for such objects in ring theory. Note that as $S$ lives in a ring it is necessarily a union of ideals.

Comment: My previous comment is correct if the ring has the unity element.

Comment: "left semigroup ideal" sounds like a viable ad-hoc term to use, if nothing better appears.